# Migration on production server with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I want to apply a migration on my server but I got an error which asks me to specify the project but when I specify the project I get an another error.

However they work in development.

Here's the first error:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

> No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.

And here, the second:

```
dotnet ef database update --project Devystri
```

> /var/www/devystri/Devystri(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

Here my migrations files:

[image: Migrations files]

Thank you !

Comment: make sure the data project is set as startup project and in package manager console try, update-database -p data

Comment: Thank you but I try to do the migration on my linux server so I don't have the package manager console

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add this in the Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                try
                {                    
                   db.Database.Migrate();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                
            }

            host.Run();
        }
```